# JS: Is it possible to set variables (as I want) on Chrome Developer Tools and firing functions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I've been trying to create the API calls on my own because there is no API access. I was trying to do it with `fetch api`. However, some security measures block me from doing that. I could not find a way to get around this.

Therefore, I am trying to find the function that the `send button` fires. Set variables according to their functions and then fire it on `Chrome Developer Tool Console`.

Will this simulate how I actually send the `POST` request manually by clicking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. There will be no way to automate this, though, and you'll need to manually paste all of your commands into the Dev Tool console every time for it to work.

A better approach is to use [Playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright) (or [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) or Selenium or similar tool), which is a headless browser that you can control with code.

An even better approach might be to see what security measures are blocking you. Is it CORS? If so, you should be able to make the requests programmatically using [Got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) or [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). If it's a CSRF token, then you likely will need to use a real browser to make the requests.

Comment: I mean i do not mind copying and pasting variables and sending requests. I can loop it to where i want it. Which is already saving so much time. 

I dont know exactly what. It is not cors or csrf token. I simulated with the exact copy of the headers and bodys. But i do not get responses when I use Fetch API on chrome dev tool.

Comment: @chichi have you tried `$('button#id').click()` (replace `#id` with a CSS selector that uniquely identifies your button)? Does that generate the correct network traffic?

Comment: Why do you not get responses? Is there an error? Does the request happen in the network panel?

Comment: So, what I have done was to send `Post Request` with the same headers and body after observing the http requests. Everything is the same. And, it returns 201 res code. However, I get an empty response. If I do it by clicking actual 'send' button, it returns data with the confirmation of changes.

Comment: @chichi so status code is 201 whether it works or not, but when you try to emulate the response, you can see in the network panel that there is no data in the response, is that correct? Have you tried emulating the response with Postman or curl, and are you able to get it to work there? It could be that it expects a constantly changing value every request (e.g. a CSRF token), or maybe there is an issue with the request. Without seeing more, it's very hard to say